# Різниця між пробачте, даруйте і перепрошую?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Коли доцільно вживати кожне з зазначених слів? На мою думку:

**пробачте** це, здебільшого, коли завинив

> Пробачай, що я нагримав зопалу *(Леся Українка, III, 1952, 222)* [SUM](http://sum.in.ua/s/probachaty)

**даруйте** - далі висловлюєш незгоду тощо

> Даруйте на слові, але ви більше ніж помиляєтесь *(Іван Микитенко, I, 1957, 78)* [SUM](http://sum.in.ua/s/daruvaty)

**перепрошую** - просити вибачення, але також ввічливе звертання, наприклад, до незнайомої людини в магазині

З іншого боку, багато прикладів з СУМ є дуже схожими. Чи є якісь нюанси використання цих слів?

Answer (score 11):

Погоджуюся із вживанням слова "даруйте", "перепрошую" вважають калькою із польської мови (*przepraszać, przepraszam*), "пробачте" та "вибачте" вважають  еквівалентами при бажанні вибачитись за ненавмисну образу чи дію. У цій статті пояснюються дані вирази в порівнянні з англійськими варіантами вибачень. Стаття досить цікава: [Особливості вживання висловлень ввічливості представниками українського та американського суспільства](http://naub.oa.edu.ua/2011/osoblyvosti-vzhyvannya-vyslovlen-vvichlyvosti-predstavnykamy-ukrajinskoho-ta-amerykanskoho-suspilstva/)

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Також підтримую @SassaNF щодо перепрошую. _Przepraszać_ одне з багатьох польських слів, що звучать схоже на українські. Чому саме це слово калька? Чи ви не знаєте якісь матеріали з теми?

Answer (score 7):

Попередня відповідь дає хороше пояснення походження цих слів, тому я зосереджуся лише на доцільності вживання варіантів у різних ситуаціях.

Приклади з сучасної української літератури, наведені у СУМ, наводять на думку, що, на відміну від англійської, в українській *усі ці слова́ вживаються майже однаково*. Тому можна говорити лише про те, як кожен надає особисту перевагу вживанню того чи іншого слова.

- У випадку *привернення уваги* співрозмовника або передуючи висловлення *прохання* — **перепрошую** [(СУМ)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereproshuvaty)
- У випадку, коли ви *збираєтеся* вчинити провину — **даруйте** [(СУМ, значення «3»)](http://sum.in.ua/s/daruvaty)
- У випадку *вже вчиненої* провини — **пробачте** [(СУМ, значення «а»)](http://sum.in.ua/s/probachaty) або **вибачте** [(СУМ)](http://sum.in.ua/s/vybachaty)
- У випадку висловлення *заперечення або незгоди* — **пробачте** [(СУМ, значення «б»)](http://sum.in.ua/s/probachaty) або **вибачте** [(СУМ)](http://sum.in.ua/s/vybachaty)

Comment: Ще можна додати: "У випадку якщо ви мешкаєте у Львівський області і щось не дочули - прошу (за результатами власних спостережень).".

Comment: @Gluttton Юрій Андрухович, «Рекреації»: «— Так довго не живуть, — сказав Немирич. / — **Прошу?** — перепитала Амальтея. / — Я кажу, що всі вони вже давно мали би повмирати, — пояснив свою думку Немирич.»

Comment: В англійській мові є `excuse`  та `sorry`, які, власне, вживаються до і після провини відповідно. `Даруйте` та `вибачте` не є еквівалентами у цьому плані.  `Excuse me, can I ... ` українською буде `Вибачте, можна я ...`. `Даруйте, можна я візьму ...` я ніколи не чув.

Answer (score 0):

Я б сказав, «пробачте» може виражати вищий ступінь каяття, ніж «вибачте», «даруйте» й «перепрошую». Якщо ви, наприклад, ненароком вбили людину, а тоді кажете її рідним «перепрошую», це звучатиме іронічно й цинічно. «Вибачте» й «пробачте» частково взаємозамінні (можливо, не всі носії їх розрізняють). «Вибачте», «даруйте» й «перепрошую», як правило, стосуються незначної провини, «пробачте» в подібних випадках менш типове.

Comment: Насправді всі ваші твердження можна перевірити за допомогою словників (і попередні відповіді дають такі посилання). Будь-ласка додайте посилання на словники які підтверджують ваші висновки.